# NoMethodError: undefined method `mail' for main:Object on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am trying to test the working of mailer. Normally on rails I first test my code logic on console level and then once it is successful I put it into the real source code. I am trying to do the same while working on ApplicationMailer. I followed some other solution and first ran the following on rails console to first set up the ActionMailer

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp 
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
  port: 587, 
  domain: 'gmail.com',
  authentication: 'plain', 
  enable_starttls_auto: true, 
  user_name: '***********',
  password: '******'
}
```

and then I ran my code:

```
y.include? x
  if true
    @receiver = Model.where(category_id: "#{x}").pluck(:email)
    mail(to: @receiver, subject: @subject)
  end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `mail' for main:Object
    from (irb):19
```

Could somebody please tell me how make this work on rails console?

Comment: do you have this line `mail(to: @receiver, subject: @subject)` in mailer?

Comment: or you are running it directly on console

Comment: Do you have mailer for this?

Comment: I'm first trying to run it on console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can test mail using following way

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: "test@example.co", to: @receiver, subject: @subject, body: "Test").deliver
```

Comment: On rails console?

Comment: Yes, run in `rails console`

Comment: Can I call this method in a controller where I actually need this function ?

Comment: For that you have to create mailer.

Comment: Refer this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Rails sets up a lot of convenience so that you can e.g. send mails from the controller easily.

In the console, you are not in the context of a controller, therefore you have not set this up already. The same would go for view-helpers.

In order to use the mail-method, you need to tell Ruby where to look for it.

It should be enough to send the mail like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: "test@example.co", to: @receiver, subject: @subject, body: "Test").deliver
```

Keep in mind that you can also use different `delivery_method`s, if you just want to test the mail-generation, but not yet the integration with your SMTP.